# Расшифровать ответ сервера

Tags: c#, json, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Добрый день! У меня есть ответ от сервера vk:

```
{ ts: 196851367, updates: [ [ 4, 16929, 1, 85635407, 1280307577, ' ... ', 'hello', {'attach1_type': 'photo', 'attach1': '123_456'} ] ] }
```

Как парсить {'attach1_type': 'photo', 'attach1': '123_456'}? Там фигурирует название attach1 - выходит, оно непостоянное?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Странный Json. Интересно, кто такой делает?

Answer (score 6):

Воспользуйтесь JSON-парсером, не пытайтесь изобретать очередной велосипед.

Например, возьмите [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) или просто [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).

Comment: Дело в том, что я уже распарсил сам JSON. Мне нудно только это
[ 4, 16929, 1, 85635407, 1280307577, ' ... ', 'hello', {'attach1_type': 'photo', 'attach1': '123_456'} ]
распарсить

Comment: @mrtaracqk Используйте JSON.NET. Вам будет достаточно написать    
var a = JObject.Parse(jsonString);    
И все будет так, как Вам необходимо.

Comment: @mrtaracqk: по идее, вам не нужны .cs-файлы, просто подключите .dll к проекту. Вам нужна только одна .dll-ка, соответствующая вашей версии .NET. Они ж рассортированы по каталогам.